# How to execute jquery Waypoints only on elements outside of viewport?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, viewport

I have a list of blocks and some of them are visible only when you scroll down. I need to have the ones not visible scaling in size from 0% to 100% once they come in viewport, kind of a lazy load effect but on the entire element instead of the image only. To do that, I add a class to the waypoint element.
Waypoints adds the class also on the elements that are already in the viewport when the page load. Is it possible to target only the elements that aren't already in viewport?

This is the function I'm using:

```
$('.post').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') $(this).addClass('animate');
}, { offset: '101%' });
```

And this is the example link
http://brainfood.clientapproval.co.uk/

If you scroll down, you'll see that the class is added to the elements already in viewport. Then you can see the desired effect on the elements outside of the viewport. Is there a way to prevent Waypoint execute on the elements already in viewport on page load? Or could you recommend other ways of doing so?

Comment: You could use a custom selector e.g, http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport  then use `$('.post:not(:in-viewport)').waypoint(...);`

Comment: You can't understand how grateful I am to you! Thank you! That was what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You should try this [**plugin**](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) which is very useful in your case , it will simply tell you if element is in view port or not ( you can fire the check everytime you scroll )

Usage as simple as:

```
$('#element').visible();
```

> This basic check will return true if the entire element is visible to
>   the user (within the visual viewport).

check this basic [**example**](http://opensource.teamdf.com/visible/examples/demo-basic.html)

Comment: Thank you, I tried the visible plugin before but with no luck. I have solved with a custom selector $('.post:not(:in-viewport)').waypoint(...); as per A. Wolff comment

Comment: no problem but i dont get why couldnt you use it ? anyway glad you have solved your issue.